# Android development with sensor accelerometer and brightness

Tags: android, screen, sensors, android-sensors, brightness

I'm developing an app that uses the sensor accelerometer. I want the display to go black for instance when a value reach 8.1 and go back to normal when 7 is reached. Is it possible without using screen brightness? I want it to be complete black and this is not possible what i know with screen brightness.

Hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Also i want the screen to be black while you are in other apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your activity. Let your main.xml load a black image -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Since you also need the screen to be black while you are using other apps. Then you need to write a background service that receives the accelerometer values and when it reaches 8.1, you can use the above snippet of code in your service.